# Convert Date "Tue Sep 25 2018" in "dd-mm-yyyy" [angular4]

Tags: angular, typescript, date, datepicker

Im trying to convert the Date in the "dd-mm-yyyy" format with no success.

Ive tried to use `this.datePipe.transform(this.filter.offerExpiration,"yyyy-MM-dd")`   but it doesnt work (the date doesnt change at all).

What can I do?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the following code, your date will not change:

```
this.datePipe.transform(this.filter.offerExpiration,"yyyy-MM-dd");
console.log(this.filter.offerExpiration);
```

The datePipe returns the modified date. This should do the trick:

```
let formattedDate = this.datePipe.transform(this.filter.offerExpiration,"yyyy-MM-dd");
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: Glad it worked. Please consider marking the answer as the right answer :)

Comment: sure, I couldnt set this as the right answer because I had to wait 10 min :)